# Problema al llamar un html desde otro html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema, creé el archivo 
***busqueda.html*** con su respectivo ***busqueda.js***, este se encargaría (porque aun no está terminado) de buscar a X cliente, empleado, proveedor o artículo en venta en mi base de datos.

Por otro lado tengo los formularios ya armados (estos formularios se encargarían por medio de *inputs* de mostrar información y darían la posibilidad de modificar dicha información) para cada situación por ejemplo ***cliente.html*** y ***cliente.js*** (***cliente.html*** tiene *inputs* con eventos asociados en ***cliente.js*** así como también botones).

Acá viene el problema, por medio de ***ajax*** llamo a ***cliente.html*** desde ***busqueda.js*** para mostrarlo en ***busqueda.html*** y lo muestra bien, salvo que ***cliente.js*** no se carga, ahora bien ¿cómo puedo hacer que ***cliente.js*** funcione?

Datos relevantes:

- Aun no conozco jQuery -de ante mano gracias si lo resuelven mediante esa
  librería, pero no me estaría sirviendo-
- Este es el fragmento de ***busqueda.html*** donde hago el `innerHTML`
  resultante del ajax:

```html
<div id="div_resultados"></div>
```

Fragmento de ***busqueda.js*** y el ***ajax***

```
function cargoformendiv(ruta){
    var conexiondb3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    conexiondb3.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (conexiondb3.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById('div_resultados').innerHTML = conexiondb3.responseText;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('div_resultados').innerHTML = "Cargando...";
        }
    };
    conexiondb3.open('POST',ruta,true);
    conexiondb3.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    conexiondb3.send();
}
```

Si precisan algún otro dato intentaré facilitárselo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La [especificacion](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) no permite ejecutar scripts's cuando se carga contenido en innerHTML:

> script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are
>   inserted.

Lo que puedes hacer es cargar todos los recursos JS en el HTML principal (busqueda.html?), pero probablemente tengas que adecuar los scripts para que funcionen a pesar de que el HTML con el que interactuan no esta presente.

Comment: gracias por responder, después de pensarlo un poco(con la mente mas despejada), lo que me decís es el camino que e de probar xd